# Input a list of n integers in an array and arrange them in a way similar to the to-and-fro movement of a Pendulum. input-1 3 2 5 4,output5 3 1 2 4

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i,j,k=0,temp=0,x,n,m=0;
    cin>>x;
    while(x--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        int a[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            {
                if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                {
                    temp=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[j+1];
                    a[j+1]=temp;

                }
            }
        }
        int b[n];
        m=(n-1)/2;
        b[m]=a[0];
        i=m+1;
        j=m-1;
        k=1;

        do
        {
            b[i]=a[k];
            k++;
            b[j]=a[k];
            i++,j--;
            k++;
        }while(j>=0 && i<=n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",b[i]);


        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:
8

539 161 985 856 166 29 726 590

Its Correct output is:
856 590 166 29 161 539 726 985

And Your Code's output is:
856 590 166 29 161 539 726 0

In the above code why is the output showing 0 as the last element though it is working fine for the sample cases.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated language tags. Your code is written in [tag:c++] and there is no C in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this test:

```
    }while(j>=0 && i<=n);
```

In case of an even number of arguments, j>=0 will be false one turn before i<=n becomes false. As a result, the last, most positive number, will not be processed. You need to find a way to handle these two end cases (i and j) separately!